# Arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have very little programming experience and I am new to Swift. I am trying to create a type of poker game and I am not sure how to set the arrays.  I need multiple players and each of these players will have multiple variables such as how much is there current bet, did they fold, how much money do they have, etc.

My questions is, I imagine this will be handled with arrays but I am not sure how to handle which player and which variable of that player I am executing commands on at any one time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you outline the code you have tried with so far?

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand what object oriented programming is. You need an array of objects. An object is defined by a class. I would recommend you watch youtube tutorials. Or go to school for it.

Comment: You are working with Swift, which is an object oriented programming language. Use that feature for your implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get down voted, because things like this can be found easily on the web. Nevertheless:

You probably would want to use `classes` instead of arrays. Especially in swift where:

> An array stores values of the same type in an ordered list

Look up for classes or read it at apple's site: [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)

A class looks like:

```
class Player {
    let name = "Pete"
    var cardArray = ["1c","1h"]                     // array of type String. "1c" and "1h" could mean "ace of clubs" and "ace of hearts", pocket ace!
    var cardDict = ["clubs": [1], "hearts": [1]]    // same as above, but with a dictionary and an array inside to make sure the combination are unique
}
```

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant `An array stores values of the same type in an ordered list`

Comment: You're right. I do not know anything about object oriented programming. I am taking an online video course to learn swift but he doesn't really cover classes in detail. I have also been watching the skipcast.com tutorials. There was one on classes but I really didn't get how they can be used. I thank all of you for taking time to help me.  I will check the *classes* link Henry Lee sent me.  His brief example has already given me a better understanding of the use of classes and I will do more research into this subject.